# jQuery equivalent of YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', requestUrl, callback, "jsonSlapInfo=" + value)

Tags: jquery-ui

Please tell me the jQuery UI equivalent of YUI,
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', requestUrl, callback, "jsonSlapInfo=" + value).
I am new to jQuery and YUI .

Comment: $.ajax({ type:"POST", url:requestUrl, callback, "jsonSlapInfo=" + value })

Answer (score 0):

first i must tell you JQuery UI is just a ui design script based on JQuery core. so its false to say you need YUI equivalent for JQuery UI.

you must search for JQuery equivalent.

here is what you want:
[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
and this one is more simple:[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Shiraz,I was asking JQuery equivalent only for the same and I have understood that,$.ajax will be used,but,m nt getting what to write for the last parameter in the YUI method.Can you check the following code,and let me know,if its fine,

Comment: $.ajax({
   
   type:"POST",
   url:requestUrl,
   callback,
   dataType: dataType

   
   
   })

Comment: in the YUI,  YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', requestUrl, callback, "jsonSlapInfo=" + value),where , var value= generateJSONObjectParameter(abcd,"jsonSlapInfo")